# css flexbox only works on resize when using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, flexbox

I am using a CSS Flexbox to stack three divs on top each other.
The middle div must grow or shrink depending on the size available.
The top and bottom div will take up the size they have.

When testing this in a fiddle it will work.
However, I am loading the data in the page using ajax and fullPage.js slider.

the result is that the middle div does not fill up the remaining space.
When I resize the window, it will trigger a change in size and everything is well.

So I have been trying to create a work around, thusfar without any success.
What I have done so far:

- try to trigger a window resize $(window).trigger('resize');
- try to change the CSS height for the flexible box
- try to reload data after 500 ms.
- setting the flexbox height to a certain height and then setting it to auto again.

and I forgot all the other things I've done so far trying to do some CSS tricks.

Here the CSS / HTML

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
}

.pageInfo {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.pageData {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.sliderBtnBar {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="pageInfo">some text</div>
    <div class="pageData">
         <div>data</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sliderBtnBar">btns</div>
</div>
```

In the wrapper I will load the pageInfo, the pageData and the sliderBtnBar divs on a later time. At that point the Flexbox doesn't work. Loading this when the page loads it will work.

So like I said, I can't find a work around.
Have you seen this before or know how to solve this?
Any idea would be helpfull.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You forgot to close `div.pageData` in your example HTML.

Comment: tnx! just closed it ;)

Comment: A reproduction of the issue always helps to get more answers.

Comment: I understand but that involves a lot of extra time (quite some dependancies). I have a work around in place, but not quite sattisfied.